# Connecting React frontend and Node.js backend at Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have deployed my simple React app to Heroku - https://projectslist.herokuapp.com It works just fine except for the server part which doesn't work at all. I've seen the logs and it says that my only server method - /sendmail - returns error 404. How can i fix this problem? I suppose that I should edit something in package.json file but I'm not sure what I should change.
Here's my github repo - https://github.com/VasVV/Projects-list

Comment: what is ur Procfile? also, in the package.json u have no script that runs the server how u are making sure that the server is indeed running? the create-react-app starts a webpack-dev-server i think. bundle ur react code and use express.static to host that maybe.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I don't have a Procfile. As for script if I edit my package.json as follows: "start": "react-scripts start && node server" will it work? And what do u mean by bundling my code and using express.static to host?

Comment: Perhaps having a different Heroku app for your server will solve your problem. Make sure to update your API URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your server files in the root directory folder and everything else in a client folder within the root:

1.) Put your server.js into the root directory

2.) Add these commands to your root package.json...

```js
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4242/"
```

3.) Create a client folder and put your src and public folders in it.

4.) Add these commands to your client folders package.json...

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Your file structure from root should look like this:

```js
Root
  client
    Public
    Src
    package.json
  server.js
  package.json
```

[image]

5.) Move all your server-related stuff into the root folder, that way, you don't have to cd into any nested folders.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help but now I receive an error "2021-07-05T09:58:54.585582+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=projectslist2.herokuapp.com request_id=ee27cab3-d6d0-4296-84ca-0863d3e8d820 fwd="88.1.81.122" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=397 protocol=https" 
My new app address - https://projectslist2.herokuapp.com/
My new repo - https://github.com/VasVV/projects-list-2

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to your root folder that says something like:

```
web: node server/index.js -port 8000
```

And a small addition to the `scripts` part of your `package.json` that tells Heroku that once it's fetched all the dependencies for your project it should build it, [although that may not be necessary now](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1557).

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but I recieve the same error as in previous answer - 2021-07-05T10:17:19.481777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=projectslist.herokuapp.com request_id=85616105-a296-4281-8cef-095e9f948ed2 fwd="88.1.81.122" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=397 protocol=https
What can I do to fix it?